# Continuity of a nonnegative integrable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

**Question:** Let $f$ be a nonnegative integrable function. Show that the function $F$ defined by 
$$ F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f $$
is continuous.

In other words, show for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$ | y - x | < \delta \quad \implies \quad \left| \int_{-\infty}^y f - \int_{-\infty}^x f \right| < \epsilon $$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Issues:** So I'm working out of Royden & Fitzpatrick (4th ed) and this question follows a chapter on Uniform Integrability (The Vitali Convergence Theorem). I was thinking I could formulate it using:
$$\left| \int_{-\infty}^y f - \int_{-\infty}^x f \right| = \left| \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} f - \int_{y}^{x} f \right| = \left| \int_{x}^{y} f \right| < \epsilon $$
but I'm not sure if this works or not, and how I would go from here.

Comment: What you want to show is uniform continuity. But continuity is enough. For this, fix $x$, let $y_n$ tend to $x$, note that $\int_x^{y_n}f\,dt = \int_{\mathbb R}\chi_{[x,y_n]}f\,dt$, and use the majorized convergence theorem.